# SCIP solver: ERROR: method createConsBasicQuadratic is not implemented yet

Tags: scip

When using SCIP solver I'm getting the following error:

```
[info] Running org.allenai.iqclid.ilpsolver.ilpModel 
[info] 18:09:25.423 [main] DEBUG o.a.iqclid.ilpsolver.ScipSolver - Java library path = /Users/danielk/ideaProjects/iqclid/lib
[error] [src/JniScipConsQuadratic.c:132] ERROR: method createConsBasicQuadratic is not implemented yet
[error] [src/JniScipConsQuadratic.c:133] ERROR: Error <0> in function call
[error] Exception in thread "main" de.zib.jscip.nativ.NativeScipException: ERROR: Error <0> in function call
[error]     at de.zib.jscip.nativ.jni.JniScipConsQuadratic.createConsBasicQuadratic(Native
```

The functions seem to exist in the core library but just not implemented in jni?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly! It's open-source so if you want to you can put in the missing code.